# Creating array of different objects

Tags: c++

I have this code, but I don't see where I went wrong here. It seem to compile OK but I cannot access `Computer` or `Appliance` functions. Can someone please help me understand how can I make an array that holds different objects on this code example I have here?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Technics
{
private:
    int price, warranty;
    static int objCount;
    double pvn;
    char *name, *manufacturer;
public:
    Technics()
    {
        this->objCount++;
    };

    Technics(int price)
    {
        this->objCount++;
        this->price = price;
    }

    ~Technics(){
        this->objCount = this->objCount - 2;
    };

    static int getObjCount()
    {
        return objCount;
    }

    void setPrice(int price)
    {
        this->price = price;
    }

    int getPrice()
    {
        return this->price;
    }

    void resetCount()
    {
        this->objCount = 0;
    }
};
int Technics::objCount = 0;

class Computer : public Technics
{
private:
    int cpu, ram, psu, hdd;
public:
    Computer() {}
    Computer(int price)
    {
        this->setPrice(price);
    }

    void setCpu(int cpu)
    {
        this->cpu = cpu;
    }

    int getCpu()
    {
        return this->cpu;
    }
};

class Appliance : public Technics
{
private:
    int height;
    int width;
    char* color;
    char* type;

public:
    Appliance(){}
    Appliance(int height, int width)
    {
        this->height = height;
        this->width = width;
    }

    void setWidth(int width)
    {
        this->width = width;
    }

    int getWidth()
    {
        return this->width;
    }
};

void main()
{
    //Creating array
    Technics *_t[100];

    // Adding some objects
    _t[0] = new Computer();
    _t[1] = new Computer();
    _t[2] = new Appliance();

    // I can access only properties of Technics, not Computer or Appliance
    _t[0]->

    int x;
    cin >> x;
}
```

Comment: Probably best to pick up a good book about C++ and wrap your head around the concepts of inheritance and polymorphism. By the way, there's no such thing as an "array of different objects": all your array elements are of the same type, namely `Technics *`.

Comment: Well, there is an array boost::variant<...>, of boost::any or of void* of course... (in rising degrees of insanity)

Comment: Of course you can access only properties of Technics, because it is a pointer to `Technics`. Also `Technics *_t[100]` is a pointer to an array of `Technics`. It is not what you want. Please use `std::vector`

Comment: Thanks I got it to work with static_cast(); If anyone has some suggestion about good book regarding this matter please leave at comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
_t[0] = new Computer();
```

Creates a computer object and stores it as a Technics base pointer in the array (i.e. for all intents and purposes while in that array, it is a Technics object).

You need to cast back to the derived class to access members that are more derived than those in Technics:

```
static_cast<Computer*>(_t[0])->Your_Member();
```

Use dyncamic cast if you don't know which derived type it is - it will return the casted pointer on success and NULL on fail so it's kind of a type-check - it has big runtime overhead though, so try to avoid it :)

**EDIT** in response to your closing comment:

```
//Calculate the length of your dynamic array.

//Allocate the dynamic array as a pointer to a pointer to Technics - this is like
//Making an array of pointers each holding some Technics heirarchy object.
Technics** baselist = new Technics*[some_length];

//Populate them the same way as before:
baselist[0] = new Computer();
baselist[1] = new Appliance();
```

PS: you could also use std::vector which is dynamically changeable as opposed to just created at run time - it's the best option if your allowed to use it.  It saves you making your own resizable array code.  Google it ;)

Comment: If you are not sure that `_t[0]` is a `Computer`, you can use `dynamic_cast` instead, but beware that it can return `NULL` if the cast fails.

Comment: Ah ok, that should teach me not to be on OS in one window, and doing work in another. :)

Comment: Haha, yeah.  I do that all the time honestly :p When you're a programmer sometimes its hard to not just read the code and ignore the rest.

Comment: Thanks man, this worked. I've searched differences between static and dynamic casts already. Anyhow I've tried to make this array dynamic by usual methods, but with no luck. If you have some time to help me out please do so and show me how can I create dynamic array of these objects now instead of static one. :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because _t is a pointer to `Technics` not `Computer` or `Appliance`.

Give Technics an "object type" parameter e.g. an enum that is `TechnicsType.Computer` for `Computer` and `TechnicsType.Applicance` for `Appliance`, check that and cast to the appropriate type to get the class methods.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can only access the properties of Technics, since your variable has type `Technics`. You have to cast it to your Computer or Appliance class in order to execute your additional methods.

You really have to think about your design here. Is it really appropiate? Why do you have all of the objects inside the same container? Especially if you have different methods to call..this doesn't make sense..

If you really want to call different methods, you probably have to use a `switch` statement to decide what type you have, then call the appropiate methods (I guess you want to iterate through the whole container, or else it doesn't make sense to have a big container with different objects).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very very simple :)

The super-class must have the virtual functions of the subclasses declared in the class definition.

For example: if the super-class **computer** have a sub-class called **laptop** that have a function `int getBatteryLife();`, so the computer class must have the definition `virtual int getBatteryLife()` to be called in the vector of pointers of the type computer.

Comment: The problem of this solution is that you must declare a lot of virtual functions in base class, one per subclass attribute you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Because `_t` is a `Technics` pointer array and, there is not possible to access to derived classes attributes. Use a Visitor Pattern like this or downcast your pointer:

```
// visitor pattern
class Visitor
{
    void accept(Appliance &ref) { // access Appliance attributes };
    void accept(Computer & ref) { // access Computer attributes };
};

class Technics
{
    ....
    virtual void visit(Visitor &) = 0;
};

class Appliance
{
    ....
    virtual void visit(Visitor &v) { v.accept(*this); }
};

class Computer
{
    ....
    virtual void visit(Visitor &v) { v.accept(*this); }
};
```